# What is the equivalent status for "Needs to Sign" when calling via the eSignature Rest API?

Tags: docusignapi

I found the following statuses under API reference - *Envelopes: listStatus* but not sure which is the equivalent status for "Needs to Sign". Can advise? Thanks.

A comma-separated list of envelope status to search for. Possible values are:
*completed
created
declined
deleted
delivered
processing
sent
signed
template
voided*

Answer (score 0):

The relevant statuses would be either `sent` or `delivered`, but that won't tell you specifically if they need the current user's action.

To do so, you would want the [Envelopes::ListStatusChanges](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/Envelopes/Envelopes/listStatusChanges) call with `folder_ids=awaiting_my_signature`